# bytes32 to string conversion is not working right in solidity

Tags: byte, solidity, remix

I am trying to convert a bytes32 to a string using this code:

```
 function convert(bytes memory data) public pure returns (string memory) {
        return abi.decode(data,(string));
    }

 function compare(string memory str1, string memory str2) public pure returns (bool) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(str1)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(str2));
    }

    function check(bytes32 temp)public pure returns(bool){
        bytes memory data= abi.encodePacked(temp);
        string memory res = convert(abi.encode(data)); 
        return compare(res, "har0");
    }
```

The bytes32 which I'm sending is 0x6861723000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

This has ending zeros which are empty bytes. But when I return the string from `function check` it gives the right result => "har0" in remix IDE
But in solidity code the string is not working like "har0" , thus `function compare` returns false !

How can I convert a bytes32 to string in a appropriate way so that I could use that string for some purpose inside the code ?

Comment: when I use `0x68617230` as `bytes` , the string works, but it doesn't when input contains excessive empty bytes at last like 0x686172300000

Answer (score 0):

see a better a approach for this would be to use Strings.toHexString which you can find in openzeppelin and then try to make the comparision.
The reason for the error comes with the trailing zeros which we need to reduce.

Answer (score 0):

cant you just cast it like:

```
 function convert(bytes32 foo) public pure returns(string memory) {
    string memory bar = string(abi.encodePacked(foo));
    return bar;
 }
```

check this out:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/how-to-convert-a-bytes32-to-string

There's also a library function such as `bytes32ToString`:

```
 function bytes32ToString(bytes32 _bytes32) public pure returns (string memory) {
        uint8 i = 0;
        while(i < 32 && _bytes32[i] != 0) {
            i++;
        }
        bytes memory bytesArray = new bytes(i);
        for (i = 0; i < 32 && _bytes32[i] != 0; i++) {
            bytesArray[i] = _bytes32[i];
        }
        return string(bytesArray);
    }
```